# using get total function in python

Tags: python

Can anyone help me finish this code please, I need to calculates the total of the numbers contained in the file and print the answer to the screen using the get_total function. I have the rest of the code running fine I just don't know how to add the numbers together and display the answer. I'm using python 3.3.2

```
def main():

     filename = input("Welcome, please enter file name:\t")
     menu()
     choice= int(input("Enter menu choice:\t"))

    while choice != 5:
         #get file choice from user
         if choice == 1:
             #create file
             create(filename)
         elif choice == 2:
             #read file
             read(filename)
         elif choice == 3:
             #append file
             append(filename)
         elif choice == 4:
             #get total
             get_total(filename)

         choice = int(input("Enter menu choice:\t"))

     print("\nApplication Complete")

 def menu():
     #user chooses a number from menu
     print("Choose a number to continue:\t\n\
     Select 1 to create a file\n\
     Select 2 to read a file\n\
     Select 3 to append to a file\n\
     Select 4 to calculate the total of a file\n\
     Select 5 to exit programme")

 def create(filename):

     #create file name
     outfile = open(filename,"w")
     again = "y"

      while again == "y":

         try:
             #user inputs integer
             num = int(input("Input number:\t"))
             outfile.write(str(num)+"\n")
             #asks user whether they want to continue or not
             again = input("Enter y to continue:\t")

         #if an error occurs
         except ValueError:
                       print("An error occured,please enter an integer:\t")

         except:
                       print("An undetermined error occurred")
      #close file
      outfile.close()

 def read(filename):

     print("\nReading File")

     try:
         #read integers entered onto file
         infile = open(filename,"r")

         for line in infile:

             number = int(line)
             print(number)

     except IOError:
             print("An error occured trying to read")
             print("the file", filename)

     except:
             print("An undefined error occurred")

 def append(filename):

     print("\nAppending to file")

     #user enters integers again
     outfile = open(filename, "a")
     again = "y"

     while again == "y":

         try:
             num = int(input("Input number to append to file:\t"))
             outfile.write(str(num)+"\n")
             again = input ("Enter y to continue:\t")

         except ValueError:
                 print("an error occured please an integer")
         except:
                 print("an undefined error occured")


         outfile.close()

 def get_total(filename):

     print("\nGetting total numbers contained in file")

     try:
         #user inputs integer
         num = int(input("Input number:\t"))
         outfile.write(str(num)+"\n")
         #asks user whether they want to continue or not
         again = input("Enter y to continue:\t")

     except IOError:
             print("An error occured trying to read")
             print("the file", filename)

     except:
             print("An undefined error occurred")          

 #call main
 main()
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
def get_total(filename):

    print("\nGetting total numbers contained in file")
    num = int(input("Input number:\t"))
    f = open(fileName)
    found = 0
    for line in f:
        for matchNum in re.findall(r'[0-9]+',line):
        if matchNum == str(num):
            found = found + 1
    print("\nNo. of occurrences of num in file :: ",found
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This block of code will be helpful for your requirement:

```
def get_total(filename):
 total_sum = 0 
 print("Calculating total of the numbers contained in file")
 f = open(filename)
 try:
     #read inputs integer
     for line in f:  
         #split the string on whitespace, return a list of numbers
         # (as strings)
         numbers_str = line.split()
         #convert numbers to int
         numbers_int = [int(x) for x in numbers_str]

         total_sum=sum(numbers_int)

 except IOError:
         print("An error occured trying to read")
         print("the file", filename)

 except:
         print("An undefined error occurred")
 # prints out the total after the loop
 print("The total {}".format(total_sum))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to create a variable to hold all the numbers you are reading in:

```
 def get_total(filename):
     total_sum = 0 # running total
     print("\nGetting total numbers contained in file")

     try:
         #user inputs integer
         num = int(input("Input number:\t"))
         outfile.write(str(num)+"\n")
         total_sum += num
         #asks user whether they want to continue or not
         again = input("Enter y to continue:\t")

     except IOError:
             print("An error occured trying to read")
             print("the file", filename)

     except:
             print("An undefined error occurred") 
     # prints out the total after the loop
     print("The total {}".format(total_sum))
```